# PL/SQL add response header

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, xmlhttprequest, plsqldeveloper

I need to add a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to my PL/SQL procedure, so that I can access the content of the webpage by another domain through a XmlHttpRequest.

Because now the following error occurs:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://db:7779/xxxxx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://domain' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501.
```

This is my javascript code of the XmlHttpRequest:

```
function httpGet(theUrl){   //gibt Daten von URL zurueck
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    //xmlHttp.withCredentials = true;     //Does this change anything for the response?
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader( "pragma", "no-cache" );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: in case your plsql procedue generates the http response including the headers, just add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain` on a single line. Otherwise, you have to add code to or configure your application or web server to have this response header added. Have a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), where the CORS mechanism is discussed.

Comment: My procedure writes data with htp.p function and I need to get this data from another webpage.. When I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to my procedure then I get errors atm while I try to compile the procedure

Comment: Or could you give me an example of how to generate the http response header?

Comment: `htp.p` writes part of the content,but you have to write a header (which is a part of the response you normally do not see). The headers are typically provided by the web server or the application server which relay the output  you generate to the requesting party.

Comment: Yeah I already know that htp.p writes the content.. So is there a way to add a Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to the response header within the procedure? How do I get access to the web/application server?

Comment: Htp.p writes the body and no headers. You will not get direct programmatic access to the web/appl server from the backend; apis may be provided though (web services, select files), but there really is no way to tell but talking to the people who manage your web/appl server. You _might_ be lucky if you're printing a complete html document and your output is sent out as is - in this case try to call `htp.p('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'||chr(13)||chr(10)||chr(13)||chr(10));` right before `htp.htmlopen`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74338/discussion-between-zerone-and-collapsar).